# How do I fix NSArray Coercion error for a UITableView and Parse?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have been Stuck on this error for awhile and I have searched and researched possible fixes for this and I cannot seem to find any. This the Same Code I used for an earlier IOS App and now it fails to work, I have taken the needed actions to update to the current Swift 3.1 Language however now I am stuck with the Following error:

`Cannot convert value of type '[PFObject]?' to type 'NSArray' in coercion`

So First off I'm not even sure where to begin fixing the Error. 
Here is the Section where the Error Shows up:

```
findUser.findObjectsInBackground {
        (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in // Changes NSError to Error
        if error == nil{

            let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
            })
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

and for ref my whole UITableView Class:

```
import Foundation
import Parse
import UIKit

class FindAParty:UITableViewController{

    var partyData:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
    var user:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

    override init(style: UITableViewStyle){
        super.init(style: style)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    @IBAction func loadData(){

        partyData.removeAllObjects()

        var findPartyData:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Party")

        findPartyData.findObjectsInBackground{
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?)->Void in

            if error != nil {
                print("Error")                
            }
            else{
                for object in objects!{

                    let party:PFObject = object as PFObject
                    self.partyData.add("Party")
                 }

                let array:NSArray = self.partyData.reverseObjectEnumerator().allObjects as NSArray
                self.partyData = NSMutableArray(array: array)

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.loadData()
    }

    // #pragma mark - Table view data source

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int { return 1 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView?, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return partyData.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
        let cell:FindAPartyCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath! as IndexPath) as! FindAPartyCell

        let party:PFObject = self.partyData.object(at: indexPath!.row) as! PFObject

        cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 0
        cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0

        var findUser:PFQuery = PFUser.query()!
        findUser.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: party.object(forKey: "UserName"))

        findUser.findObjectsInBackground {
            (objects:[PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in // Changes NSError to Error
            if error == nil{

                let user:PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as! PFUser
                cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    cell.typeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.timeOfPartyLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                })
            }
        }            
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: I suggest using native swift array instead of NSArray/NSMutableArray and removing the cast of objects to NSArray, just access the first property as a swift array

Comment: you should use native array and dictionary along with appropriate let and var because it's all about mutable and non mutable things. Which is causing problems in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to convert swift native `Array` type to `NSArray` to access just `lastObject` of array you need to simply use `last` property of native `Array` instance.

```
if let user = objects.last {
     cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
}
```

In Swift use native `Array` and `Dictionary` instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`. So it is batter if you declare your `partyData` as `[PFObject]` instead of `NSMutableArray`.